# Setting the value of a SwiftUI slider by tapping on it

Tags: slider, swiftui

How can I change the value of a SwiftUI `Slider` by tapping on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a minimal implementation I created using a [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) that rounds to the closest value:

```swift
struct TappableSlider: View {
    var value: Binding<Float>
    var range: ClosedRange<Float>
    var step: Float

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Slider(value: self.value, in: self.range, step: self.step)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded { value in
                    let percent = min(max(0, Float(value.location.x / geometry.size.width * 1)), 1)
                    let newValue = self.range.lowerBound + round(percent * (self.range.upperBound - self.range.lowerBound))
                    self.value.wrappedValue = newValue
                })
        }
    }
}
```

which can be used just like a normal slider, e.g.

```swift
TappableSlider(value: $sliderValue, in: 1...7, step: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Up date some thing here :

```
struct TappableSlider: View {
    var value: Binding<Double>
    var range: ClosedRange<Double>
    var step: Double

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Slider(value: value, in: range, step: step)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged { value in
                    let percent = min(max(0, (value.location.x / geometry.size.width)), 1)
                    let newValue = (percent * range.upperBound).round(nearest: step)
                    self.value.wrappedValue = newValue
                })
        }
    }
}
```

whith extension Double here :

```
extension Double {
    var clean: String {
        truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }

    func round(nearest: Double) -> Double {
        let n = 1 / nearest
        let numberToRound = self * n
        return numberToRound.rounded() / n
    }

    func floor(nearest: Double) -> Double {
        let intDiv = Double(Int(self / nearest))
        return intDiv * nearest
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you add explaination for your post?

Comment: This is not a question, please refer to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct to write clear, relevant questions.